# Problems importing certificates and provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

So I started experimenting with iOS development on a borrowed Mac. I kept all my certificates + provisioning files I created there. I bought a Mac yesterday for development.

I have imported my development + distribution certificated into keychain. They are listed under "Keychain | login | Certificates" without errors. (They are not listed in "Keychain | login | My Certificates). I have

- Developer ID Certification Authority
- IPhone Developer: My name (ID)
- IPhone Distribution: My company (ID)

So far so good, but XCode is somehow lost it seems. I have the following:

Under "XCode : Teams" I have:
My company: iOS Distribution
My name: iOS Development
In here I have following error at top:
"Unable to code sign using identities in this eam: no valid certificated with private keys found)

Under XCode : Provisioning Profiles I have:
 - DevelopmentMyCompanyApp - AppID
 - DistributionMyCompanyApp - AppOD
 - iOS Team Provisioing Profile
All these have the "Status" : "Valid signing identify not found

Have I done something wrong? I kinda thought that if I kept certificates + provisioning files, I would be able to import it all? (Maybe I made a small importing certificates after provisioning profiles, but a **refresh** does not solve it either)

Comment: I ended up revoking all the old stuff and just accepting the situation. I will look into backing uop certificates the next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export your private key from your old Mac to your new one. What you have to do if you can't get it is generate a new one. Go into your keychain and go to the Certificate Assistant and request from CA, and save it to disk. Upload it in Apple Developer, and generate your new certificate and install it.

You can also create a new provisioning profile for Dev and Distro, and associate your newly generated cert with it. XCode should show everything green under organizer (i'm assuming now it shows all yellow).

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for your answer. Just to be 100% sure, does that mean the certificate files are no longer valid? Even though I can download them from https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action they are essentially useless to me now? If correctly understood, should I revoke them?

Comment: if you are still using the certs on your previous mac, then you don't want to revoke them. what you could do is export your certs from your new mac, and load them on your old them, so they won't be obsolete. Then once your new Mac's are using the new certs, you can revoke the old one(s)! My two macs are currently using two separate certs and profiles, but i'm thinking about consolidating them.

Answer (score 2):

I also go with AmitApollo's answer, because that is some solutions. But there is another solution with Xcode. That is..

You goto your Xcode's organizer and select team and export them with secure password. In the new Mac's Xcode you just import them then you will see it will get all the informations.

Comment: Upvoted: I don't have access to the old Mac although I gues I could borrow it again. Not sure what is easiest. As I have not actually released any app yet, I guess I could do it all again without any unforseen problems?